# Which is the better way to run a long running impersistance task in a multi module android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, rx-android, android-workmanager

I have a multi module architecture android project, where there are modules like module A, module B, module C and shared common module. Each modules code is private. Other modules cant access directly, shared module is the only module which is accessible by every other module.

Scenario:

In Module A, I need to call a sdk method, Which takes around 5 min, which gives a continuous progress values in integer. That progress is shown in dialog box. Now user hides the dialog box and moves to other part of the app say ex: Module B's fragments.
I need to make sure that sdk method is still in progress and able to get that progress in Module B as well.

Solutions tried:

1. Workmanager: If i try to add a sdk method code in doWork method and start the workmanager. Able to observe the progress through live data in other component. However i am facing a limitation in starting a workmanager since to start a sdk method inside doWork method i need to pass a object to sdk method. That object is more than 10Kb so cant pass it through workparameters and also cant globally save that object due to security issues.
2. Coroutines: If i just tried using scopes, there is no common viewmodel between multiple modules. so if i start a sdk method from Module A, If user moves to different module's fragment viewmodel destroys.
3. Foreground service: I cant use foreground service. Due to security issues i cant show the device notification.

So is there any better approach to accomplish the above task?

i have gone through android background doc of google [Android Background doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) Google suggest to use workmanager for long running persistance case. But mine is a requirement of long running impersistance case.  however one more requirement of mine is during sdk call. If app closes, I dont want to resume that task as well once app restarts.

Comment: Is the call to the SDK method blocking or asynchronous?

Comment: @zomega It's an asynchronous

Comment: I think you are talking about the Android SDK? Which method is it you are talking about?

Comment: no .. its a third party sdk .. we have a hardware connected to our app through bluetooth ..

Comment: Could you please add code that shows how you call the SDK method and how you get the progress? I can't say anything without seeing the code.